# Describe what it means for a map to be well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So my answer is "A map is considered to be well-defined if the operation does not depend on choice of operation. i.e. $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ where $\phi([n])=n.$ This is not well defined because $\phi([4])=4$ and $\phi([10])=10$ but [4]=[10]." Do you think this is a good way of describing well defined?

Comment: Yeah it looks right to me. You showed that elements from the same equivalent class gives you something different.

Comment: It boils down to showing that the relation is acually a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, though your use of the word "operation" doesn't quite make sense. You could just as well simplify the statement to

> A map is considered to be well-defined if it does not depend on a choice.

(Note also that you misused "*i.e.*". You should have instead used "*e.g.*".)

However, it's actually quite difficult to explain "well-defined" since it's kind of a bad choice of terminology. Timothy Gowers has an excellent blog post, [Why aren’t all functions well-defined?](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/), that goes into this further.